# How to exclude a Maven dependency from the environment of an annotation processor?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

## Context

I have code that uses maven-processor-plugin to have Hibernate generate some classes in folder `src/main/generated` of a Java project. I am preparing the migration of the project to Java 11, in the development environment as well as in the runtime environment.

Until now, everything worked fine with Hibernate 4.3.10.Final and Java 8. After installing JDK 11 and using Hibernate 5.4.4.Final, I've come across the infamous `javax.annotation.Generated` problem.

Since Hibernate 5.4.4.Final is supposed to be compatible with Java 9+, I was expecting the generated files to switch to `javax.annotation.processing.Generated`. Unfortunately, the old qualified name is the one that I can still see in those files, in the imports section. As a consequence, the compilation of generated files will fail.

Here is what I configured:

- maven-processor-plugin, with `<releaseVersion>11</releaseVersion>`
- The target level in pom.xml, with `<maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>`
- The release in pom.xml, with `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>`
- In Eclipse, the Java compiler is using the '--release' option and set to compliance level "11".
- On the system, there's only one JDK installed: 11.0.4.

On further investigation, I have realized that the `Context` class in org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.4.4.Final has this code:

```
        TypeElement java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation =
                pe.getElementUtils().getTypeElement( "javax.annotation.Generated" );
        if ( java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation != null ) {
            generatedAnnotation = java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation;
        }
        else {
            // Using the new name for this annotation in Java 9 and above
            generatedAnnotation = pe.getElementUtils().getTypeElement( "javax.annotation.processing.Generated" );
        }
```

## Question

Essentially, the Hibernate annotation processor tries to determine which correct annotation (of `javax.annotation.Generated` and `javax.annotation.processing.Generated`) to output in the generated files by trying to get a reference to the Java 8 `javax.annotation.Generated` type. I guess the premise is that that type would not exist in a Java 9+ environment.

But unfortunately for me, javax.annotation:jsr250-api is indirectly pulled by org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin as a transitive dependency into the build environment of my project.

My question is therefore: how can I exclude that transitive dependency from the environment that is passed to the Hibernate annotation processor?

I'm also wondering whether it's an issue that I should report to Hibernate or the maven-processor-plugin projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did that works is shown below.

A thing to note is that there needs to be an intermediate artifact between the root plugin (maven-processor-plugin in this case) and the dependency to exclude (jsr250-api in this case).

My earlier mistake was that I was listing maven-processor-plugin again in lieu of maven-plugin-api, which of course did not make sense.

```
    <pluginManagement>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-processor-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <releaseVersion>${maven.compiler.release}</releaseVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-plugin-api-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <!-- 
                            Exclude this artifact because it defines 'javax.annotation.Generated', which makes the 
                            generated source code incompatible with Java 11.
                        -->
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </pluginManagement>
```